# How to modify the drop-down box length of QCombobox while keeping the original box length unchanged?

Tags: c++, qt

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJ1cX.png)

How to get the top half of the image, but not the bottom half?

```
int width = ui->comboBox->minimumSizeHint().width();
ui->comboBox->setMinimumWidth(width);
```

This method will change the length of the original box together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is achievable via the stylesheet in this way:

```
ui->comboBox->setStyleSheet("QComboBox QAbstractItemView {min-width: 1000px;}");
```

This code changes only the minumum width of the down list.

[QComboBox Modified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mpq8.png)

Comment: This is very useful!

Answer (score 0):

if I think right, you want to change the item's list that will open when clicking on the combo box area?
the item's list area automatically will be resized to content size and you should set maximum width instead of minimum width.

Comment: If I set the maximum width, then the dropdown box will not change.The function setMinimumWidth seems to change the width of the combobox together, and I only want to change the width of the dropdown box

Comment: in our application this is ok and the dropdown panel resizes to all contents. maybe a parent forces them to change their dropdown size. create a simple GUI project and check them, if still resize the dropdown according to maximum width may you need to update your qt version. I tested them on Qt 5.15